# wordpress custom fields arrangement

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

In my wordpress theme I am creating some custom fields like

> cp_street, cp_city, cp_mobile_no, cp_company_name

and much more. Which is displayed in **single_ad_listing.php** page, and code is

```
cp_get_ad_details( $post->ID, $cat_id );
```

and theme-function.php page code is

```
// display all the custom fields on the single ad page, by default they are placed in the list area
if ( ! function_exists('cp_get_ad_details') ) {
    function cp_get_ad_details( $post_id, $category_id, $location = 'list' ) {
        global $wpdb;

        // see if there's a custom form first based on category id.
        $form_id = cp_get_form_id( $category_id );

        $post = get_post( $post_id );
        if ( ! $post )
            return;

        // if there's no form id it must mean the default form is being used
        if ( ! $form_id ) {

            // get all the custom field labels so we can match the field_name up against the post_meta keys
            $sql = "SELECT field_label, field_name, field_type FROM $wpdb->cp_ad_fields";

        } else {

            // now we should have the formid so show the form layout based on the category selected
            $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT f.field_label, f.field_name, f.field_type, m.field_pos FROM $wpdb->cp_ad_fields f "
                . "INNER JOIN $wpdb->cp_ad_meta m ON f.field_id = m.field_id WHERE m.form_id = %s ORDER BY m.field_pos ASC", $form_id );

        }

        $results = $wpdb->get_results( $sql );

        if ( ! $results ) {
            _e( 'No ad details found.', APP_TD );
            return;
        }

        // allows to hook before ad details
        cp_action_before_ad_details( $results, $post, $location );

        foreach ( $results as $result ) {

            // external plugins can modify or disable field
            $result = apply_filters( 'cp_ad_details_field', $result, $post, $location );
            if ( ! $result )
                continue;

            $disallow_fields = array( 'cp_price', 'cp_currency' );
            if ( in_array( $result->field_name, $disallow_fields ) )
                continue;

            $post_meta_val = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $result->field_name, true );
            if ( empty( $post_meta_val ) )
                continue;

            if ( $location == 'list' ) {
                if ( $result->field_type == 'text area' )
                    continue;

                if ( $result->field_type == 'checkbox' ) {
                    $post_meta_val = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $result->field_name, false );
                    $post_meta_val = implode( ", ", $post_meta_val );
                }

                $args = array( 'value' => $post_meta_val, 'label' => $result->field_label, 'id' => $result->field_name, 'class' => '' );
                $args = apply_filters( 'cp_ad_details_' . $result->field_name, $args, $result, $post, $location );

                if ( $args )
                    echo '<li id="' . $args['id'] . '" class="' . $args['class'] . '"><span>' . esc_html( translate( $args['label'], APP_TD ) ) . ':</span> ' . appthemes_make_clickable( $args['value'] ) . '</li>';

            } elseif ( $location == 'content' ) {
                if ( $result->field_type != 'text area' )
                    continue;

                $args = array( 'value' => $post_meta_val, 'label' => $result->field_label, 'id' => $result->field_name, 'class' => 'custom-text-area dotted' );
                $args = apply_filters( 'cp_ad_details_' . $result->field_name, $args, $result, $post, $location );

                if ( $args )
                    echo '<div id="' . $args['id'] . '" class="' . $args['class'] . '"><h3>' . esc_html( translate( $args['label'], APP_TD ) ) . '</h3> ' . appthemes_make_clickable( $args['value'] ) . '</div>';

            }
        }
```

All fields display serially, but I want to like address `cp_street, cp_city` top of page and mobile no.( cp_mobile_no) right side of page and rest of fields display same place.

Please help me...

Comment: Now you want create the graphic view of the page? You have to implement the php code in html page, giving style using css, is this what you want do?

Comment: I am arranging this custom field which is display serially, I want like address (street, city, state, country) display top of the page, and mobile no. display right side of the page and rest of the field display same place. please help me this codding.

Comment: Thanks Alessio for replay, please see my website (http://www.opendeals.in/ads/online-jobs-in-india-without-any-investment/) then you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In this tutorial we will look at how the Advanced Custom Fields plugin can be used to create a professional home page .

[i hope this like use full.. here simple code..](http://www.elliotcondon.com/using-the-advanced-custom-fields-plugin-to-create-a-custom-home-page-in-wordpress/)

Comment: I have already create custom field and work fine. I am arranging this custom field which is display serially, I want like address (street, city, state, country) display top of the page, and mobile no. display right side of the page and rest of the field display same place. please help me this codding.